# Optimizing memory usage for Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, heroku, scalability, resque

I have a Rails 4 app on Heroku with Resque and Resque Scheduler each running on separate 1x dynos. I currently have 3 Resque workers spun up.

Here is my `Procfile` for reference:

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 bundle exec rake resque:workers QUEUE='*' COUNT='3'
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

When I profile the memory usage I can see that at idle, my `resque` dyno is consuming 390MB of 512MB of available memory, while my `web` dyno is consuming only 262MB of memory. At first glance this seems ok since I have plenty of head room.

When I queue up 40 emails to be sent out on the `resque` dyno though, memory usage spikes up to 480MB. If I queue more it grows until it exceeds the dyno's capacity and I get an R14 error. Note that I'm not sending the emails using the SendGrid API rather than through SMTP, but I still have to `render_to_string` each email template (looking into a more efficient route for that), which is what I suspect is consuming a lot of memory.

What I would like to know is what the best approach is here to optimize my resource consumption on Heroku? I use `Resque` mainly for image processing and sending batch emails. I currently have 3 workers spun up on one dyno, but I'm not sure if I should have more or fewer workers on one dyno or spread across multiple dynos. The current usage of the app is fairly low most of the time, however I expect the usage to increase greatly in the near future and am thus concerned about scaling. For example, right now I may have one user per day batch upload 100 photos at once, or send out 50 emails at once. I'm anticipating a 10 fold increase in the usage soon though.

I'm not looking for a specific answer per se, just advice on how to optimize my resource usage and scale up smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku did a nice write-up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-resque-pool) on utilizing the resque-pool to reduce the memory overhead of resque workers.

> The resque-pool gem scales out your resque based workers by running multiple workers per dyno, and is a good fit. The resque-pool gem behaves similarly to the Unicorn web server in the way it is designed. It boots one master process and then uses the unix fork command to create multiple resque workers that can all process your data independently. These multiple resque workers create your “pool” of workers. Using processes for concurrency is safer in Ruby but can have a higher memory overhead.

The usage of this gem also applies to running resque workers outside of the Heroku ecosystem as well.